# ClassCastException while executing my app with minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, gradle, broadcastreceiver, proguard, classcastexception

I have an Android system app that has a custom BroadCastReceiver in manifest (this is to be run in Android M device):
My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
    package="mypackagename">

   ....

    <!-- custom permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="mypackagename.ASK_DISPLAY_INFO"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"/>

    <permission android:name="mypackagename.ASK_DISPLAY_INFO" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
         
        ....

        <!-- custom receiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".CustomReceiver"
            android:permission="mypackagename.ASK_DISPLAY_INFO">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="GET_HDMI_SUPPORTED_MODES"/>
                <action android:name="CHANGE_HDMI_RESOLUTION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

And I have enabled in gradle Proguard obfuscation:

```
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         
        }
```

I have another test app that sends broadcasts to this app. The thing is, with mignifyEnabled false works, but with mignifyEnabled true when receives a broadcast intent it gives the error:

***java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver mypackagename.CustomReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: mypackagename.CustomReceiver cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver***

Adding the following rule to proguard-rules.pro:

-keep class android.content.BroadcastReceiver { *; }

When receiving an intent throws the error:

***java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.content.BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)"***

Here is my broadcastreceiver definition:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "CustomReceiver received action: "+intent.getAction());

            if (intent.getAction().equals(GET_HDMI_SUPPORTED_MODES)) {
                new GetHDMIModesTask(context).execute();
            }  else if (intent.getAction().equals(CHANGE_HDMI_RESOLUTION) && intent.getExtras() != null && intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_HDMI_MODE) ) {
                new ChangeHDMIModeTask(context, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_HDMI_MODE)).execute();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

As I'm very new to Proguard rules and I need this obfuscated, I would appreciate if someone can tell me which rules can I specify to solve this issue

Comment: seems like the issue is in `CustomReceiver` so post make sure it extends `BroadcastReceiver` and imports are appropriate

Comment: Hello, thanks, for your answer, I've added my broadcastreceiver to the post.

Comment: if you are using broadcast with separate apps then add `android:exported="true"` though for pro guard, the answer by Nikhil should fix the issue, clean and generate new apk and try again

Answer (score 0):

Add `-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver` to your proguard rules instead of `-keep class android.content.BroadcastReceiver { *; }`. This will prevent your custom broadcast receiver from being obfuscated.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion, I've added to proguard rules: `-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver` but still returns the first error: **_java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver mypackagename.CustomReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: mypackagename.CustomReceiver cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver_**

Comment: Try keeping both lines - 
`-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver`
and
`-keep class android.content.BroadcastReceiver { *; }`

Comment: Adding both rules throws the second error: **_java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.content.BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)_**

Comment: Try adding  
```-keepnames class your.package.name.ClassName {

}```
to explicity tell proguard not to obfuscate the class.

Comment: it doesn't build: AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Expected [!]interface|@interface|class|enum","sources":[{"file":"C:\\...\proguard-rules.pro","position":{"startLine":34,"startColumn":11,"startOffset":1295}}],"tool":"R8"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Have you changed package name with your package name?

Comment: Yes, I have: -keepnames class mypackagename.CustomReceiver { }

Comment: Post your proguard rules file here.

Comment: I just have these: `
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep class android.content.BroadcastReceiver { *; }
-keep public class mypackagename.CustomReceiver {
     public void onReceive(Context, Intent);
}`

Comment: Try preserving native methods of Broadcast Receiver by adding - 
```-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}``` along with other rules.

Comment: It gives the same AbstractMethodError

Answer (score 0):

I have done a workaround in this, removed CustomerReceiver from manifest, added an custom application class and defined the BroadcastReceiver in there. Added the proguard rules:

```
 -keep class android.app.Application {
        public <fields>;
        private <fields>;
       public <methods>;
    }

    -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

The issue was gone